# Restore backbone state after navigating away and then back

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a Backbone Marionette app which allows users to search using various criteria. From the search results they can click on a link which navigates them away from the backbone app to a standard static page.

How can I set things up so that when they click back in their browser, the backbone search page is restored back to their previous state (with search criteria and results intact)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use backbone router for your search page and save state in location.hash, so all population/rendering will be managed by router or views which will listen to router events:

> "route:[name]" (params) — Fired by the router when a specific route is matched.
>
> "route" (route, params) — Fired by the router when any route has been matched.

For example #search/query/nuggets will trigger this route:

```
'search/query/:query-string': function(query) {
    yourCollection.fetch({data: {query: query}})
}
```

and in your view

```
initialize: function() {
   this.listenTo(yourCollection, 'sync', this.render)
}
```

so then user click/or hit enter in your search field you just should trigger route change: `yourRouter.navigate("search/query/"+yourQuery, {trigger: true})`